# Is indentation semantically meaningful or syntactically meaningful in Python

Tags: python, grammar, terminology, semantics

I came across the sentence,

> In Python, indentation is semantically meaningful.

I'm not sure I understand what "semantically meaningful" means here.

Also, since indentations are used to delimit the if and else blocks of coniditional expressions in Python, wouldn't they be considered to be part of the language grammar and therefore "syntactically meaningful"? (I cannot find mention of them in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=conditional#conditional-expressions) for conditional expressions.)

Comment: They probably should have said syntactically.

Comment: When you look at the meaning of the root of the word, semantic, you see that it is defined as "relating in the meaning of language or logic". I guess whoever wrote semantically thought it was the correct use of the word due to that definition. However, syntactically would have been more precise.

Comment: ...eh, it's arguably both. Changes the parsing, so it's syntax; that parsing changes the actual meaning, so it's also modifying the semantics. But agreed that syntactic is more precise.

Comment: I'm not sure this use of "semantically meaningful" is semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they should have said "semantically meaningful", but the distinction is somewhat fuzzy. [TechDifferences](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-syntax-and-semantics.html) says:

> The syntax of a programming language is a collection of rules to specify the structure or form of code whereas semantics refers to the interpretation of the code or the associated meaning of the symbols, characters or any part of a program.

Since indentation determines things like whether a line is part of a function or loop, and that impacts things like variable scope, it could be considered to affect the "associated meaning" of the symbols.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I just figured that since it also affects the structure of the AST, it must also be "syntactically meaningful". I wanted to ask here to be sure because the author then goes on to say that since indentation is semantically important, the notion of a line is also important. This is still confusing to me - I understand now why indentation can be thought of as being semantically meaningful, but I'm not sure how newline significance follows from this.

Comment: Oh I think I understand (maybe) - using indentation to indicate structure wouldn't be of much use if newlines weren't also significant, i.e. both are needed in Python to make sure that the visual structure of the code corresponds to its semantic structure. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The real point is that it doesn't really matter whether whether it's syntax or semantics. All that matters is that indentation is significant, unlike most other languages where it's just for making it more readable to humans.

Comment: Unless you're writing a compiler or a CS theoretician, the distinction between syntax and semantics is not very important.

Answer (score 2):

This question is mostly useful for pedantry, since the answer won't change the way you write your code.

However, I would say: in Python, leading spaces are syntactically meaningful, and indentation is semantically meaningful.

The number of spaces at the start of a logical line (in the sense as defined in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines)) defines the indentation level for that line, by comparing the number of leading spaces to the same number for the previous logical line. It either matches the previous number (continue current block), is greater (increase level and start new block) or matches a previous number of spaces (decrease level, end current block, continue matched block). If it doesn't match a previous level, that's an indentation error. That's the syntactic meaning of leading spaces.

Once Python knows the indentation level, that decides the meaning of the line (i.e. continue a block, start a new one, or continue a previous block and ending the current) - these are the semantics of the indentation level.

In other words: leading spaces are syntax, indentation is semantics.

Comment: I think you are distinguishing between lexing and parsing; semantics comes into play once the parser has constructed a syntax tree and you need to assign some meaning to that tree. I'm not aware of any cases where differing indentation can construct two identical ASTs with different meanings.

Comment: I think that's fair, you can argue that the INDENT and DEDENT tokens are still just syntactic elements and the semantic meaning only arises from the interpretation of those tokens for the logical line that follows. I don't think it changes the answer though.

Comment: *Leading* spaces are syntactic, by your definition. There's no syntactic distinction between `a     +    b` and `a + b`. Spaces can be lexically significant (`2j+4 .real` and `2j+4.real` differ lexically); it could be argued that creating `INDENT` or  `DEDENT`s is lexical rather than syntactic, if you think there's a difference between "lexical" and "syntactic". Here's a question very similar to this one: are the parentheses in `2*(3+4)` semantic? They definitely change the meaning of the expression (by changing the parse). Personally, I think all these distinctions are basically arbitrary.

Comment: Anyway, plusone for the first sentence. Precisely.